# Auto running SQL script with Azure database server

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database, command-line, automation

I am trying to automate a report that is generated from the database on Azure database server. I am using below script in the batch file but I get the error.

Script:

osql -U firstname.lastname@company.edu -S aazdb01.c224.database.windows.net  -P "Password" -s "|" -i "c:\Users\fl1\Desktop\script.sql" -o "c:\Users\fl1\Desktop\output.txt"

Error:

Cannot open server "company.edu" requested by the login.  The
login failed.

---

If I run the below script with 'Sqlcmd', I still get the error.

Script:

sqlcmd -S aazdb01.c224.database.windows.net -U firstname.lastname@company.edu -P "Password" -s "|" -i "c:\Users\fl1\Desktop\script.sql" -o "c:\Users\fl1\Desktop\output.txt"

Error:

Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server : Cannot open server "company.edu" requested by the login.  The login failed..

Can anyone advise what is the issue here?

Comment: If you are trying to use an Azure Active Directory username and password add the `-G` switch.  Read the requirement for using this switch in the help for sqlcmd here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlcmd-utility?view=sql-server-ver15  Both sqlcmd and the ODBC driver have to be fairly up to date.

Comment: Brian, thank you for sharing that link. So I did use -G but I get the error message 

Error:

Sqlcmd: 'G': Unknown Option. Enter '-?' for help.

Script:

sqlcmd -S aazdb01.c224.database.windows.net -U firstname.lastname@company.edu -P Password -G -s "|" -i "c:\Users\fl1\Desktop\script.sql" -o "c:\Users\fl1\Desktop\output.txt"

Comment: As I said: **Both sqlcmd and the ODBC driver have to be fairly up to date.**

Comment: Thanks Brian. So I do have   1. Microsoft Command Line Utilities 11 for SQL Server
2. Microsoft Command Line Utilities 15 for SQL Server

3. Microsoft ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server
4. Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server